# Calling additional service functions after a resolved promise in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angular-promise

In Angular I have a service to access the google contacts api, then store all my contacts into variable (`StorageVar`) to be analyzed by other functions in the service.

Should I call one of the analysis functions before getting the data from the API, I want to call the `getAPI` function then (as in `.then()`) run the analysis function. The issue is that I can't figure out how to access any of the functions from the `.then()` scope.

```
angular.module('API',[])
.factory('API', ['$rootScope', '$http','$q', function ($rootScope, $http, $q) {
    var StorageVar = [];
    return{
        getAPI: function(){
            //does async call, returns promise, stores data into StorageVar
        }
        Analyze: function(){
            if(StorageVar.length==0){
                 //need to get the data first
                 this.getAPI().then(function(){
                     //Analyze()
                     debugger;
                 }
            }
        }
```

In my controller I would want to use my service like this:

```
angular.module('views.local', ['API'])
.controller('localctrl',['API',function(API){
    API.Analze()
    //Callable even if the getAPI function hasn't run, so the Analyze function will take care of that.
}])
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: So can you show an example on how would you consume your API factory?

Comment: @Wawy, I edited the question to add more about the controller I am using. Is that what you mean?  I might also implement a promise structure for the Analyze function if it needs more API calls, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

Comment: what functions do you want to access inside .then callback function?

Comment: @Wawy ideally I would like to access service functions like `Analyze()`. This way I could call the Analyze() function from my controller, and then it would see if the StorageVar was empty and if so, do the API calls then run Analyze() again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
angular.module('API',[])
    .factory('API', ['$rootScope', '$http','$q', function ($rootScope, $http, $q) {
        var StorageVar = [];
        return{
            getAPI: function(){
                //does async call, returns promise, stores data into StorageVar
            }
            Analyze: function(){
                if(StorageVar.length==0){
                     //need to get the data first
                     var _this = this;
                     this.getAPI().then(function(){
                         //Analyze()
                         _this.Analyze();
                         debugger;
                     }
                }
            }
```